# How to make a button not to submit the form?

Tags: php

```
<form>
    <button type=submit>save</button>
    <button onclick="create();return false;">click</button>
    <textarea id="some">Testing</textarea>
</form>
<script>
function create(){
    window.location.href="some.php";
}
</script>
```

Though I have added `return false` in the onclick event, when I click the button it gets submitted. How to make that button to stop from form submission. If I have some other function in the `create()` function instead of redirecting, `return false` code will stop from submission. But here am redirecting the page so `return false` is not working.

I tried putting `return false` code in `create()` function too but no luck.

How to stop the form submit ?

Comment: Why not use JQuery and preventDefault method.

Comment: remove `type=submit`?

Comment: No,save button should be submitted

Comment: So what you are trying achieve?

Comment: In that form I have two buttons: "save" and "create". When I click save button form should be submitted. When I click create button form should not be submitted

Comment: See my post, im sure the solves your problem :)

Answer (score 1):

```
<button type=submit>save</button>
```

Should be:

```
<input type=submit value="save" onclick="create();return false;"/>
```

And

```
<button>click</button>
```

Comment: In that form I have two buttons: "save" and "create". When I click save button form should be submitted. When I click create button form should not be submitted

Answer (score 0):

USE..

```
<input type="button"  onclick="create();">
```

Comment: Then once try...
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="create();"><input type="button"></a>

Comment: `<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="create();"><input type="button" value="create"></a>` worked fine.

Comment: This would be the alternative way and it worked fine  but what would be the solution for my question @ annam priyatam

Comment: Actually, the way you are trying is right.. but even am not aware why it's not coming.. Sorry...

Answer (score 0):

As in create function you have redirected page so actually form is not submited but page is redirected.

Comment: Instead of redirecting,form is getting submitted

Answer (score 0):

If you use the button like

```
<button type="button">foobar</button>
```

it won't submit the form as long as you don't bind some js functions on it.

If you don't give this attribute `type="button"` the form takes it as a normal button and trys to submit it. Same like if you would add the attribute `type="submit"`.